# Dropdownlist selected value is reset to first item

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have tried to look through many questions about the dropdownlist and still yet to resolve my issue.

I have a Dropdownlist and a Submit button. When Submit button is clicked after value selected, it should update the Label text with the selected value of the Dropdownlist. However, what happened was each time value is selected from dropdown, it refreshes the page and the value captured was the first item in dropdownlist. How do I capture the selected value correctly before it refreshes?

Am at wits end, not sure where went wrong.

*All items in dropdownlist are unique. No duplication.

My codes:

ASP.NET

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCode" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCode_SelectedIndexChanged"/>
        <br />
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true"/>
        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="updProgress" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                <img alt="progress" src="img/loading.gif"/><br /><h2>Loading...</h2> 
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>

        <br />
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
            <ContentTemplate>

                <asp:Button ID="submitBtn" runat="server" cssclass="btn btn-success" OnClick="submitBtn_Click" Text="Submit"/>
                <asp:Label ID="lblCode" runat="server"/>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlCode" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged"/>
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
```

Code behind

```
string ddlSelectedIndex = "";   

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!IsPostBack)
   {
      //This is to load code into dropdownlist which works fine. 
      LoadCode();
   }
}

protected void ddlCode_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
     ddlSelectedIndex =(ddlCode.Items[ddlCode.SelectedIndex].Text).Substring(0, 4);
}


protected void submitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     lblCode.Text = ddlSelectedIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it without the "AutoPostBack=True" on the DropDownList... the way your code is written, it causes the page to refresh any time the DropDownList value changes. What you want is a postback when submit is clicked.

Comment: it does stop the refreshing but still captured the first index in dropdown even though I chose other value.

Comment: What populates ddlCode?  If it's a list of strings, maybe you just need the value ddlCode[ddlCode.SelectedIndex].Substring(0,4) (without .Text) or you might just use ddlCode.SelectedItem.Substring(0,4).

Comment: Also, remember that ASP.Net is stateless - unless you are setting a Session variable, that value might be gone by the time you click submit - you could verify that by setting a breakpoint and looking at the value of ddlSelectedIndex when the label gets set.  Why not just include that code in SubmitBtn_Click and use whatever is currently chosen in the dropdownlist at that point?

Comment: I have tried too by putting it under SubmitBtn_Click. However, still the same. Although the item in dropdown does not change, when print out it is the first item in the list. The ddlCode populates string e.g. M100, M102, M103 etc..

Comment: A string is what you are looking for, so if that's what it is populated with, I would use ddlCode.SelectedItem.Substring(0,4) in the SubmitBtn_Click method, and remove the trigger and code behind for selected index changed...  If that doesn't work, set a breakpoint somewhere in SubmitBtn_Click and drill down into ddlCode  - see what VS thinks the selected index, selected item, and selected value are.  Also, check your output window to make sure nothing is throwing an exception...

Comment: I tried your suggested ddlCode.SelectedItem.Substring(0,4). The selected item is always the first index. I think the issue is coming from why is it always selecting the first index in the dropdownlist ? is there additional setting or parameter I need to set to avoid from resetting it to index 1?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117764/discussion-between-mellissa-and-elemental-pete).

Comment: Hey, i managed to resolved the issues, thanks for your guidance that leads me to check on my loadCode() function. Apparently, why it kept chose the first index was because there were two columns added into the dropdownlist (which was bind from a datatable). I believe whenever we select item from the dropdownlist it will pick the index of first column instead of the second. I'm bad at explaining. Anyhow, thanks a lot for help to omit looking at the ASP and SubmitBtn_Click function all the time.